# Auto Convert to GoogleDocs format doesnt work for automatic upload

Tags: php, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am trying to upload my folder system using "gsutil"  command line, which i am able to do it succesfully.

I have made a setting on my google docs that convert each of document to google doc format.

When i do manual upload it auto converts each document to google doc format but when am doing automatic upload it does not format any of the documents.

Please let me know what i am doing wrong or is it possible to do it?

Thanks

Comment: As you might be aware, gsutil allows you to upload files to Google Cloud Storage.  The convertion of files has to do with Google Drive. When you mention you are uploading manually, where are you uploading these files to?